# How to load a large csv file by chunking columns instead of rows in pandas

Tags: csv, pandas, dataframe, chunking

We can load a large csv file as row-chunks through (e.g.) below:

```
from pandas import *

tp = read_csv('large_dataset.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)  # gives TextFileReader, which is iterable with chunks of 1000 rows.
```

One might argue that using 'usecols' is the solution; however, in my experience, 'usecols' is, qualitatively, not as fast as using 'chunksize'. Because, I presume that the entire file is still read into the memory when 'usecols' is used, and yet 'chunksize' iterates through the file, instead; hence, faster.

How could we load a large csv file as column-chunks?

Comment: CSV files aren't designed to be read that way - they're row based... If you want to chunk by N many columns each time, you'd have to re-read the entire rows each time for each load...

Comment: I have transposed the already-created-row-based files with the help of this python package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transposer/0.0.3 , and used 'chunksize'.

Comment: That's gained you nothing... that's basically loaded the entire file into memory all at once anyway... You've not gained anything over just using `read_csv` here (and heck - it's not even dealing with the nuances of CSV files anyway...)

Comment: I agree with you; however, in my particular cases, the csv files need to be fetched more than once; hence, transposing the csv files once is useful.

Comment: I would advise moving the contents to a SQL database such as MySQL or PostGres. You can then query the data by columns easily and without reloading the whole file.