# How to read a large csv file without opening it to have a sum of numbers for each row

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I'm working with a large csv file (>500 000 columns x 4033 rows) and my goal is to have the sum of all numbers per row, with the exception of the three first cells first of the row that are only descriptive of my samples. I'd like to use the pandas package.

The dataset is something like this:

```
label   Group     numOtus   Otu0000001  Otu0000002  Otu0000003  Otu0000004  ... Otu0518246  sum
00.03   1.118234  518246    0           62          275         0           ... 5            ?
```

I've tried a couple of different things, none of them worked.

I can't simply use read_csv from pandas and then work with it because the file is too large (4 Gb). So, I tried a for loop, opening one row at a time, but I'm not getting what I was expecting. The final output should be a column with the sum per line. 
Any ideas?

```
lst = []
for line in range(4033):
    l = pd.read_csv("doc.csv", sep = "\t", nrows=1, low_memory=false)
    l = l.drop(columns=['label', 'Group', "numOtus"])
    x = l[list(l.columns)].sum(axis=1, numeric_only=float)
    lst.append(x)
```

Comment: your code is reading only the first row 4033 times,

Answer (score 2):

One other solution besides dask is to use `chunksize` parameter in `pd.read_csv`, then `pd.concat` your chunks.
A quick example:

```py
chunksize = 1000
l = pd.read_csv('doc.csv', chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True)
df = pd.concat(l, ignore_index=True)
```

Addition: 
To do something with the chunks one by one you can use:

```py
chunksize = 1000
for chunk in pd.read_csv('doc.csv', chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True):
    # do something with individual chucks there
```

To see the progress you can consider using tqdm.

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

chunksize = 1000
for chunk in tqdm(pd.read_csv('doc.csv', chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True)):
    # do something with individual chucks there
```

Comment: I think they should calculate the num before concatenating, shouldn't they? Otherwise I don't see how they avoid their memory error problem

Comment: @Peter Leéh I''m trying this approach but it is taking too long. Even when I do %timeit to predict how much time will take, the code doesn't finish running. Any idea of what I can do?

Comment: ```%timeit``` is not for prediction, that will run the function multiple times. As I see in your question the problem is that the ```chucksize``` parameter specifies the number of rows per chunk. The real bottleneck is that you have over 500k columns and just 4033 rows. Try to lower chunksize to be around 500 - 1000 or even lower.

Comment: @SandraSilva I updated the answer again. What output you get by adding tqdm?

Comment: Then you should just wait  for the final output.

Comment: @Péter Leéh, thank you. Sorry for taking some time to understand what you were suggestion, but I don't have a lot of experience. Now the problem is that the sum isn't correct. It is giving 0.0 as a result for every row. I'm doing: `chunksize = 500000 

 for chunk in pd.read_csv('OTU_abundance_matrix.shared', chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True): 

     row_sum = row_sum.append(chunk.iloc[:,3:].sum(axis = 1, skipna = True, numeric_only=float))`

Comment: The issue there is you have kind of an inversion: csv's are designed to have few columns and more rows, unlike your example. This is why it's hard to work with that. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388480/how-to-load-a-large-csv-file-by-chunking-columns-instead-of-rows-in-pandas) is a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`dask`](https://dask.org/), which is specially built for this.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

dd.read_csv("doc.csv", sep = "\t").sum().compute()
```

Comment: Thanks! I din't know about dask. 

However, I get this error: 
ValueError: Sample is not large enough to include at least one row of data. Please increase the number of bytes in `sample` in the call to `read_csv`/`read_table`

Comment: Did you try increasing `sample`, e.g. calling it with `sample=1e9`?

Comment: @SandraSilva sorry, my bad, I meant `sample=10**9`

Answer (score 0):

u can use `pandas.Series.append` and `pandas.DataFrame.sum` along with `pandas.DataFrame.iloc`, while reading the data in chunks,

```
row_sum = pd.Series([])
for chunk in pd.read_csv('doc.csv',sep = "\t" ,chunksize=50000):
    row_sum = row_sum.append(chunk.iloc[:,3:].sum(axis = 1, skipna = True))
```

Comment: When I start running the code, it never gets to the end. Even %timeit doesn't finish running. Any idea of what I can do?

Comment: can you run the code `i=0` `for chunk in pd.read_csv('doc.csv',sep = "\t" ,chunksize=50000):` `print(i)` `i+=1`